# how scale is used in d3.geo.mercator?

Tags: d3.js, scale, projection, mercator

I was looking at the d3 vector tile example on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5616813.

What I am trying to do is layout this on Google Maps, so I'm changing it with the Google Maps projection.

However, it seems not work that well. So I went back to the example and I try to understand the scale and translate used in this example, but could not..

can anyone explain a bit more for me about the following codes?

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.center([-122.4183, 37.7750])
.scale((1 << 21) / 2 / Math.PI)
.translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Here it is easy to understand the center and translate, but what is the scale used here?

Thanks for the help!